# Pdf export issue

Tags: reactjs, pdf, pdf-generation, react-pdf

@progress/kendo-react-pdf

Hi i am using this library in my react project, it's working fine everywhere, but it's not working in IOS Safari, it's also working fine with MAC safari, also not showing any error please help and thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.